# Return me the value of $emit in the same component Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-bus, emit

I want to passing the data to another component by using the eventbus.
 In main.js, I set the event bus and everything works properly, except for the code below.
    when I emit the data
    COMPONENT 1 (component which emit data)

```
emitovanje () {
    EventBus.$emit("UnverifiedCars", this.numberOfunverifiedCars)
}
```

and now in the second component I do

COMPONENT 2 (component which recieve data)

```
 created () {
            EventBus.$on("UnverifiedCars", numberOfunverifiedCars => {
              console.log(numberOfunverifiedCars)
   //this code return me data in Component 1

            })
        }
```

Comment: I want only numberOfunverifiedCars from component 1 to component 2. numberOfunverifiedCars is only one number which I want print in Component 2.This is communicate between adjacent components. I can use Vuex but I spent too much time on this and I want to finish it with the eventbus

Comment: how you get variable=`EventBus` inside both component? by `import`? if so, show us that file which you import. or you inject your event bus instance to Vue root instance?

Comment: I main.js export const EventBus = new Vue();
in component import { EventBus } from './main.js';

That is no problem. 
Problem is on code above and EventBus..
Child to child compoonent..